# How to sync all attached files from G-suite mailboxes to a SharePoint libraries

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am wondering if there is a method of a way to synchronize all the files attached

- **From** a G-suite mailboxes
- **To** a SharePoint libraries

Can you suggest to me any scripts or tools that respond to this business need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Power automate flow.

- Start from this template that does almost exactly what you want:
  `Save my email attachments to a SharePoint document library`

[image]

- Delete the default Outlook trigger.
- Use the Gmail trigger called `When a new email arrives`

[image]

- Update the flow to use Gmail's connector to save attachments to a SharePoint library:

[image]

Comment: Alright, i understand, however this will only work when there is a new attachement, what about the old files in Gmail Attachements ?

Comment: Well, you can start with my suggestion first. Then, as a step 2, you can download all Gmail attachments and manually upload them to SharePoint. Doing step 2 is a little beyond the topic of this forum, but here one suggestion I googled for you: https://www.msoutlooktools.com/blogs/how-to-take-backup-gmail-with-attachments-guide.html